# RealmSwift import error

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have installed RealmSwift's dynamic frameworks in version 0.98.2.
(CocoaPods didn't work.)

I get the following error:

```
module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/Users/adambella/Documents/Pesti_I.munka/FrontSide/FestivalApp-iOS/./Realm.framework/Headers/Realm.h"
        ^
/Users/adambella/Documents/Pesti_I.munka/FrontSide/FestivalApp-iOS/./Realm.framework/Headers/Realm.h:21:9: error: 'Realm/RLMArray.h' file not found
#import <Realm/RLMArray.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Realm'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the import the framework not with an absolute path, but just as seen below.

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
```

In addition please navigate to your target’s “Build Settings”, and make sure that the parent path to RealmSwift.framework is included in the “Framework Search Paths” section.

Comment: Does that `#import <Realm/Realm.h>` statement go in an Objective-C bridging header?

Comment: Yes, this statement would go in an Objective-C header. But this shouldn't be necessary at all, as we recommend to avoid using RealmSwift in mixed apps. If you use RealmSwift, you should be always able import it via `import RealmSwift` from Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried install it statically?
Just drag and drop the **"Realm.framework"**, **"RealmSwift.framework"** files to your xcode project and check "copy items if need".

Then add the frameworks to the Embedded Binaries in your target project.
http://s8.postimg.org/6cmfwglkj/Captura_de_pantalla_2016_02_25_a_las_9_42_20_a_m.png

Answer (score 0):

**Clean build folder**

Build folder location is

Users/{home_directory} /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app_name} -bxffdjvuyjrewicuwaxocbbgxzrq